# Iphone Restarts after relaunching the app from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, ios7

I relaunches the ios app from bacground to foreground - iphone restarts and says backbaordd crash
Please find the below crash logs for your reference

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
Triggered by Thread:  5

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192a7dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ed20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5cf14 __CFRunLoopRun + 932
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185d9ddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   backboardd                      0x00000001000e7a60 0x1000e0000 + 31328
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000019299ba9c start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192a7daa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000192981998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192a7dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b02a18 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 236
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b9422c thread_fun + 24
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17e18 _pthread_body + 164
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17d70 _pthread_start + 136
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b15550 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192a7dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ed20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ceb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185d9ddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185df3454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   IOMobileFramebuffer             0x000000018bf3e484 iomfb_runloop_thread + 312
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b15550 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CoreAnimation.IOMFB.wireless
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192a7dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ed20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ceb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185d9ddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185df3454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b58a20 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::thread_body(void*) + 344
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b9422c thread_fun + 24
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17e18 _pthread_body + 164
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17d70 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b15550 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CoreAnimation.IOMFB.primary
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libGPUSupportMercury.dylib      0x000000018b658694 gpus_ReturnContextErrorKillClient + 12
1   AGXGLDriver                     0x0000000184a77248 SubmitPackets + 196
2   AGXGLDriver                     0x0000000184a6c3a0 glrSetPrivateInteger + 284
3   GLEngine                        0x000000018870427c gliSetInteger + 4592
4   OpenGLES                        0x00000001887f11e8 -[EAGLContext swapNotification:forTransaction:onLayer:] + 152
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b562c0 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBDisplay::finish_update(CA::Render::Update*, unsigned int) + 1348
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b5c0a8 CA::WindowServer::Server::render_for_time(double, CVTimeStamp const*) + 1536
7   QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b58bf4 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::vsync_callback(__IOMobileFramebuffer*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, void*) + 220
8   IOKit                           0x0000000186d9fe70 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 360
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e50a8c __CFMachPortPerform + 188
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5f03c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ef9c __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 440
12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5d1c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1616
13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185d9ddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185df3454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
15  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b58a20 CA::WindowServer::IOMFBServer::thread_body(void*) + 344
16  QuartzCore                      0x0000000188b9422c thread_fun + 24
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17e18 _pthread_body + 164
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17d70 _pthread_start + 136
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b15550 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  IOHIDService - RunLoopCompatibilityThread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000192a7dca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ed20 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185e5ceb0 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185d9ddcc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185df3454 CFRunLoopRun + 108
5   IOKit                           0x0000000186dc23bc __IOHIDServiceRunLoopCompatibilityThread + 184
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b17d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000192b15550 thread_start + 0
```

Totally what causes this issue and also kindly suggest me how to debug this issue..

Comment: I am seeing this in Console output - Terminating in response to backboardd's termination

Comment: I could be mistaken but I believe Core Animation requires you to run on the main thread, which Thread 5 clearly is not. And it's doing Core Animation *stuff*.

Comment: If Springboard or iOS itself is restarting, then surely there's a bug in iOS itself, and this should be logged with Apple.  (Of course, there may also be a bug in your code that is tripping it up.)

Answer (score 3):

Your app gets terminated by the ios for any one of the reason below,

- High memory usage or the springboard crashes( springboard is application that manages the other applications like home screen, app icon etc).
- Testing your application in jail broken devices.

Try to pause your animation stuff while resigning the application and resume them while user entering back to the application. Something like this,

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

     // pause sprite kit
     SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
     view.paused = YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     // resume sprite kit
     SKView *view = (SKView *)self.window.rootViewController.view;
     view.paused = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use `OpenGL`? Or some kind of framework, that works with camera.
Rendering surfaces is forbidden in background.

Try to handle background/foreground state changes to pause/resume rendering.

You can user `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` for this.

Comment: in my case it's not exactly OpenGL, but SpriteKit. But I got you. Gonna try to check bg state..